# HTML : Encoding special characters : name vs code

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters

A question about encoding special characters in HTML (specifically for emails):
Is there a difference in encoding a character using its name or its code ?

For exemple, is it better to use `&percnt;` or `&#37;`?

I haven't found anything on the topic. I've got a feeling the name version is used for readability of the code, but the code version would be more widely supported.

In practice, we are having a problem with Outlook, who I think doesn't know `&percnt;` I'm thinking of moving to encoding all "difficult" characters with their code, but I'd like to be sure this won't cause compatibility problems in other clients...

Comment: Why encode anything except `<`, `&`, and `"`? Support for UTF-8 is excellent this century … and `%` is in ASCII!

Comment: Why do you want to encode the percent sign?

Comment: "Better" is subjective and depends on personal interpretation of the relative weight of various factors (such as maintainability, support (among the unspecified target audience), and efficiency)